# capturing R matrix list

Tags: r, list, matrix, variable-assignment

Below piece of code is generating what I need but I am not able to store it so that I can use it further.

In the case below, I want to store each player's hand in a list of matrices `p` such that `p[i]<-deck2[smpl,]`.

The second thing I want is to save and use the final matrix of `deck2` (i.e say with 10 players, it will be a 29 row matrix). I can see NROW(deck2) as 29 but the assignment of `d<-deck2` is not happening. What am I missing here?

```
deck2=matrix(c(rep( c(2:10,"J","Q","K","A"),4),rep(c("C","D","H","S"),rep(13,4))), ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("rank","suit")))

player_hands=function(players)
{   if(players >= 2 && players <= 10) {
                for(i in 1:players) 
                { 
                smpl <- sample(1:NROW(deck2),2,replace=F)
                r <- deck2[smpl,]
                p <- deck2[smpl,]
                deck2 <- deck2[-smpl,]
                print(r)
                    if(i==players)
                    {   smpl <- sample(1:NROW(deck2),3,replace=F)
                        r <- deck2[smpl,]
                        p <- deck2[smpl,]
                        deck2 <- deck2[-smpl,]
                        print("Dealer Hand")
                        print(r)
                    }
                    else i=i+1
                }                       }
    else print("Invalid No. of Players")

}
```

Comment: `d<-deck2` doesn't appear in your code anywhere. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: sorry for confusion.you can ignore that.that was just previous name given for final deck2.because deck2 list not updating after each iteration decrement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want. It will return a list containing two items.

The first of these two items is the list of hands `p`, of which the last one will be the dealer's hand.

The second of the two items it returns will be the new deck2.

```
player_hands=function(players)
{   if(players >= 2 && players <= 10) {
        p = list()
                for(i in 1:players) 
                { 
                smpl <- sample(1:NROW(deck2),2,replace=F)
                r <- deck2[smpl,]
                p[[i]] = r
                deck2 <- deck2[-smpl,]
                    if(i==players)
                    {   smpl <- sample(1:NROW(deck2),3,replace=F)
                        r <- deck2[smpl,]
                        p[[players+1]] <- r
                        deck2 <- deck2[-smpl,]
                    }
                    else i=i+1
                }
                return(list(p, deck2))         
                              }
    else print("Invalid No. of Players")

}
```

Comment: This is perfect.However now to modify and add an extra row (i.e change its dims )of the p[i] list element seems complicated.rather thinking to add a new custom matrix p[players+2] is simple for doing operations.which is better?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: THanks Philip. its resolved now.i tried this -> https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-June/053343.html